# InnoDB transactions and REST

Tags: php, mysql, rest, transactions, innodb

I hope my question is suitable for this site and is not too broad but I am having trouble designing the following architecture:

I have two sites. Site 1 is responsible for transferring credits between users. Site 2 is responsible for providing these users with services/products which can be paid with the credits they own in Site 1.

Lets say I have 1000 credits on Site 1. I have a service/product which costs 50 credits on Site 2 and a user wants to purchase it with his amount of credits he owns in Site 1.

Both sites communicate with REST. So for example when a user wants to purchase a service/product Site 2 prepares its request and sends it to Site 1 which makes the transaction and confirms to Site 2 that the transaction was successful (e.g. the user had enough credits for the service/product and those credits were successfully transferred to the destination)

Now here's the tricky part. In Site 1 I have the following logic:

```
Begin transaction
update user set credits -= 50 where id = 1
update user set credits += 50 where id = 2
REST CALL (Site 2) Success
Site 2 response - OK, commit transaction
Commit
```

Since REST is a call to a different site the transaction might take some time to complete. In the mean time is the whole table locked for any transactions or are the rows for user 1 and user 2 locked? Is this the proper way to implement my logic? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to your question on Casey's answer:

Yes, as long as you do it like this:

- **Site 2:**

  1. Customer logs in.
  2. Ask Site 1 for credit total & transaction history (GET request) for this user (user 1).
  3. (Any awaiting transactions which receive 'transaction succeeded' responses are made available for download/dispatch)
  4. Use credit total to enable "Buy" buttons for things that can be afforded.
  5. Customer clicks a Buy button
  6. generate a transaction ID unique to site 2, store in database along with details of who bought what, when they did so, with state = pending. tell user transaction has been received and they should be notified soon whether it was successful (HTTP 202 response)
  7. POST purchase request to Site 1, including authentication (don't want forged requests to cause people to spend money they don't want to spend) and the transaction ID.
- **Site 1**

  1. validate authentication
  2. verify that Site 2's transactionID has not been used before by site 2. if it has, return an error, if not:
  3. Begin transaction
  4. update user set credits -= 50 where id = 1
  5. update user set credits += 50 where id = 2
  6. insert into transactions remoteSiteID = 'Site2', remoteTransactionID = tID, user = 1
     You would not need the remoteSiteID field if site2 is the only site using credits from site1
  7. Commit
  8. REST CALL (Site 2) Success
- **Site 2:**

EITHER:
1. Receive REST success call, make purchase available for download/dispatch, display some message to user saying purchase processing complete. Update local transaction record, state=succeeded.

OR
2. Site 2 is down. Transaction success will be noted next time background polling process runs (which checks status of purchase requests awaiting responses) or next time customer logs in (in which case poll is initiated too--step 3 in first list)

If you have not received a response to a transaction, perform a GET using the transaction ID. If the response is an error, Site 1 did not receive the original request, Site 2 is free to repeat the transaction (POST) request. If the response is 'transaction failed' then the user didn't have enough credits, update transaction record on site 2 accordingly. if result is 'transaction succeeded' record that too.

if a transaction fails N number of times, or a certain period elapses since the user clicked the button (say 5 minutes) then Site 2 stops retrying the purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using primary keys and not ranges, it should be row-level locking. There's also the concept of a shared vs exclusive lock. Shared locks allow other processes to still read the data while an exclusive is used in an update/delete scenario and blocks all others from reading it.

On the logic in general.. if there's really only *one* place storing the credits and *one* place reading them, how important is it to sync in realtime? Would 3, 5, or 10 seconds later be sufficient? If Site 1 is completely down, do you want to allow for Site 2 to still work?

Personally, I would restructure things a bit:

- A user creates an account on Site 1.
- The first time a transaction is done on Site 2, it validates the account exists on S1 and gets the number of credits.. and keeps it.
- Whenever a transaction is done on Site 2, you check the local credit count (cache) first and *if there are enough credits* you return a [202 Accepted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) response code. It basically means "hey, we accepted this but aren't done with it yet."
- You can immediately allow the user to continue at this point.
- **But** at the same time you did the local credit check, you made another request to S1 with the actual transaction.
- Hopefully, that service can give you a success/failure message *and* the update **definitive/official** credit count.
- Using that, you update the local transaction status to 204 NO Content (success) and update the cache for the next time.

Since S1 is always returning the definitive current credit count, you don't have to worry about maintaining the credit count on S2 in a 100% accurate way.. you can just wait for it from S1.

If you're *really* nervous about it, you could have a job that runs every N hours that polls S1 requesting updates on every account updated during that N hours.

Comment: The things I want to make sure never happen are race conditions and failure at either ends which can cause transfer of credits but not actual purchasing of service or the other way around. Does your approach cover that?